# How can i store PDO objects

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Right now every time i need to run a query i call a function named `connection()` that creates a new PDO object.

```
function connection(){
    $host   = 'localhost';
    $user   = 'user';
    $pass   = 'password';
    $dbName = 'db_name';
    new PDO("mysql:host=$host; dbname=$dbName", $user, $pass);
}

$db = connection();
$query = 'SELECT ...';
$stmt  = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
```

The problem is the web site takes exactly 1 second to create this object and, as you can image, if i need to run 4 queries the page will load in 4 seconds. So, is there any way i can store this PDO object to optimize performance?

I'm using this function in multiple files so i need it.

Comment: Store it in a variable and pass it around ?

Comment: Your query works? Because I think that `$db` is null...

Comment: Are you using MVC? Create it inside the `__construct()` method as a class variable inside your Model and reference it from there. If you're not using MVC, store the actual `$db` variable at the beginning of your code and reference it in your other code. Also, the `connection` function is not returning your new PDO object. I'm curious if that's functioning right now?

Comment: perhaps use the Singleton design pattern to create your DB object?

Comment: check out this article: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/design-patterns-the-singleton-pattern--cms-23073

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe

```
function connection(){
    static $CONN;
    if (!$CONN) {
        $host   = 'localhost';
        $user   = 'user';
        $pass   = 'password';
        $dbName = 'db_name';
        $CONN = new PDO("mysql:host=$host; dbname=$dbName", $user, $pass);
    }
    return $CONN;
}
```

This might do what you want without much extra change.

Comment: It's a sort of very basic pseudo-singleton implementation

Comment: yeah but why not do it properly?

Comment: I'm trying to help with the problem at hand. Maybe it's worth rewriting the entire codebase; maybe not.

Comment: At least use [static](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static) instead of global.

Answer (score 2):

What if you make a config.php file that you include at the top of your page. You only need to create the object once, and all queries on the page can reference the same object:

```
function connection(){
    $host   = 'localhost';
    $user   = 'user';
    $pass   = 'password';
    $dbName = 'db_name';
    new PDO("mysql:host=$host; dbname=$dbName", $user, $pass);
}

$db = connection();

$query = 'Statement #1';
$stmt  = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();

$query = 'Statement #2';
$stmt  = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();

$query = 'Statement #3';
$stmt  = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();

$query = 'Statement #4';
$stmt  = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Several people has mentioned static and the Singleton pattern. This is what the code would look like, keeping only one instance of the PDO object around at one time:

```
class DB{

     private static $_instance;
     private $_pdo;

     public static function getInstance(){
         if(self::$_instance === NULL) {
            $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=dbname;host=host';
            $user = 'user';
            $password = 'password';
            // call constructor and assign instance
            self::$_instance = new self($dsn, $user, $password);
        }

        return self::$_instance;
    }

    /**
     * Creates new DB wrapping a PDO instance
     *
     * Constructor is private because this class can't be instantiated.
     *
     */
    private function __construct($dsn, $user, $password){
        try {
            $this->_pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
     }

    /**
     * Singletons may not be cloned
     */
    private function __clone() {}


    /**
     * Delegate every method call to PDO instance
     *
     * @param  String $method
     * @param  Array  $args
     * @return Mixed
     */
    public function __call($method, $args) {
        return call_user_func_array(array($this->_pdo, $method), $args);
    }
}

// To instantiate:
$db = DB::getInstance();
```

Comment: Please note that [you should never catch errors to report them](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors)

Comment: You're right. This was a quick demo, focused on development, not production.

Comment: "Never" means **neither on deveopment or production.** Nor in quick demos.